# flow combine doesn't trigger but collect does

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I have a typical Android MVVM project (Compose -> ViewModel -> Repository -> RoomDB) and have simplified concept in demonstration below.

**What am I trying to achieve?:**
I want to read two flows from a Room Dao (@Query(...) fun getAll(): Flow<List>) from my repository. They should be combined into a single flow and then returned to my viewModel.
From the viewModel I want to transform the flow into a StateFlow that can be observing for as long as the viewModel lives. In the example below I propagate this StateFlow value to a mutable state "item" just to be able to display value in UI for demonstration.

**The problem:**
The combine method on the flow doesn't trigger any changes back up in the hierarchy, neither does collectLatest on a single Dao flow when I try debugging. The funny thing is that collect does...

**Now onto the demonstration:**

```
class ViewModel(private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) {

    private val repository = Repository()

    val item = mutableStateOf<String?>(null)

    init {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            repository.item.stateIn(coroutineScope).collect {
                item.value = it
            }
        }
    }

    fun click() {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            repository.increaseItem()
        }
    }
}

class Repository {
    private val dao = Dao()

    val item: Flow<String> = flow {
        // This does NOT trigger
        dao.dbItem.combine(dao.dbItem2) { value1, value2 ->
            emit("$value1|$value2")
        }

        // This does NOT trigger
//        dao.dbItem.collectLatest {
//            emit(it)
//        }

        // This does trigger...
//        dao.dbItem.collect {
//            emit(it)
//        }
    }

    suspend fun increaseItem() = dao.increaseDbItem()
}

class Dao {

    val dbItem = MutableStateFlow("0")
    val dbItem2 = MutableStateFlow("A")

    suspend fun increaseDbItem() {
        dbItem.emit("${dbItem.value} 0")
        dbItem2.emit("${dbItem2.value} A")
    }
}

@Composable
fun AtteTest() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val viewModel = ViewModel(coroutineScope)

    TestAppTheme {
        Surface {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)) {
                        Text("Value:")
                        Text(viewModel.item.value ?: "")
                    }
                    Button(onClick = {
                        viewModel.click()
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "click")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewAtteTest() {
    AtteTest()
}
```

Comment: `combine` is actually expected to not trigger any action, because it is an intermediate operator and it doesn't execute any actions by itself. I'm not sure about the `collectLatest` though. Are you sure you use exactly the same code, you only switch between `collect` and `collectLatest` and it differs in the behavior?

Comment: Ahh thanks, I changed so that the item property returns the combine and not a flow containing the combine. Yes I used the same code as in the example (The example can be copied into Android Studio and be run as a Preview). I did however manage to get the collectLatest to work when I switched from using flow to a callbackFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Works after the following changes:
Return the combine instead of a new flow containing the combine

```
class Repository {
private val dao = Dao()

val item: Flow<String> = dao.dbItem2.combine(dao.dbItem) { value1, value2 ->
    "$value1|$value2"
}

suspend fun increaseItem() = dao.increaseDbItem()
}
```

The issue with collectLatest was solved by changing from a flow to a callbackFlow:

```
 val item: Flow<String> = callbackFlow {
    dao.dbItem.collectLatest {
        send(it)
    }
    awaitClose {  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1. Your view model should extend *androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel()*. By doing so you can also drop the *CoroutineScope* parameter and use the inherited `viewModelScope` property instead. In your activity you can then retrieve an instance of this view model by             `val viewModel: ViewModel by viewModels()` and pass it down to your composables. (You should probably rename your view model so it does not share the same name with its parent class.)
2. As a general rule of thumb, don't collect flows in the view model. What you *should* do is to directly create a `StateFlow` from the repository flow (you can then remove the `init` block):

```
val item: StateFlow<String?> = repository.item.stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    initialValue = null,
)
```

3. In your composable you only access the `value` property of the flow. What you want instead is to subscribe to the flow by calling any of the `collect` methods. If you only access the `value` property you retrieve the current value, but if there are no subscribers, the state flow might decide that there is no need to produce *new* values. What you want is to collect the flow in your composable with `val item by viewModel.item.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` (best location would be where you retrieve the view model and then just pass the `item` variable down to your other composables). `collectAsStateWithLifecycle()` is a special collection method that takes the lifecycle of your composable into account. You need to add the dependency `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose` to your gradle file.

Applying these changes reduces your code and should fix the erratic flow behavior you experienced.